# Is it possible to make a dynamic AR app with CMS?

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I want to make a dynamic AR app. Can you guide me?

I want to have a CMS of targets and streaming assets to display. User must make only one install and updates will be made via SYNCH.
Can you give me inputs on this like SDKs and APIs to use, step by step in general.

I am familiar with Unity and Vuforia but for static stuff.
The back-end user must upload audio-visual content, 3D models and links against the various markers available (CRUD interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content delivery for audio & visual is assenbundles. Use Addressables for that, very easy to use.

For AR I would consider ARFoundation at first, Vuforia usually is alternative for that, not the first choice. The only tricky thing dynamic AR targets, it might not work easy.
The rest logic is up to u.

P.S. about one install thing - don't put too much hopes on that idea. You might reduce updates count with content delivery, but u almost for sure could not create only version 1.0.0 and have no updates after.

Comment: AR Foundation only supports this? No another external CMS?

Comment: AR Foundation is good but it is supported by few devices. But i will make research on it.

Comment: If by CMS u mean Content Managment System then no. ARFoundtion is not CMS. It is Unity adopted solution that gathers ARCore & ARFoundation to ease work with AR within Unity. In Unity context CMS is a little loose definition. U have to be more specific.

Comment: Does AR Foundation has a web API that I can use to add more targets and asset bundles?

Comment: This not ARFoundation's job, it is NOT cms. You should use other solutions for that. As I mentioned before - Addressables for Unity content. Other stuff is up to u.